# Deleting elements with remove_if in a nested vector

Tags: c++

I have created class Human with 2 properties :name and age,and I want to delete all elements in the nested vectors of type Human ,who have age==20 ,here is my implementation

```
class Human
{
public:
    string name;
    int age;
    Human(string name,int age):name(name),age(age){}    
    bool isAge20(const Human human) {return human.age == 20;}

    static void removeElement(vector <vector <Human> > vvi)
    {
        vector< vector<Human> >::iterator row;
        vector<Human>::iterator col;
        for (row = vvi.begin(); row != vvi.end(); row++) {
        row->erase( std::remove_if( row->begin(), row->end(), isAge20), row->end());
    }
};
```

Strangely when I create such a nested vector and call the removeElement function with it , I get the following error : must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer member function in .. .What can be the cause?

Comment: [OT]: As you pass `vvi` by value, you only change the vector locally.

Comment: `isAge20` should be `static`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks that really worked,any explanation why :?

Comment: `isAge20` is a member function and requires an instance to call it: `human.isAge20(human2)`.

Answer (score 0):

The Predicate should be a callable (function/functor), `isAge20` is a member function. You may use something like:

```
static void removeElement(vector<vector<Human>>& vvi)
{
    for (auto& row : vvi) {
        row.erase(std::remove_if(row.begin(), row.end(),
                                 [](const Human& human) { return human.age == 20; }),
                  row.end());
    }
}
```